# How do I hook up a UIViewController to a TabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How do I hook up my viewcontroller to the TabBarController? Is there something I need to do in IB? I am just using the generic tabbar template from xcode and I can see where you can make new view controllers inside of the Main.xib file in inspector but I don't know how to hook up my custom view controller to a tab in the controller. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag them into the tab bar, and voilà!